# Advice on camcorder that supports USB-C and 3.5mm external microphone?

Tags: camcorder, action-cam, presentation

I'm shopping for a video camera that I will use to record lectures that I give at my university. My setup is going to be a camcorder on a tripod plus a Lavalier wireless microphone, which I will attach to my shirt while I am presenting. There won't be a person controlling the camera; I'll just set up the camera at the beginning of class and leave it there to record. Also, I can't guarantee that I'll have external power for the camera.

I'm trying to choose a camcorder or action camera for this. Here are the features I am looking for:

- 3.5mm input jack for external mic (must have)
- usb-c or micro-usb port for charging and data access (must have)*
- screw hole for tripod (must have)
- 1h30m recording time without external power (must have)
- at least 720p resolution (not too fussy)
- price under $300 US

  *I already have usb-c and micro-usb devices in my life. I see that a lot of camcorders still use mini-usb-B, which feels ancient now. I don't want an other type of cable to carry around.

Can anyone offer any advice on this?